# How to install Skype on Fedora 22 64 bits

Tags: linux, fedora, skype, fedora-22

I have searched hour for posts about this subject and have found many posts about possible solutions but have yet failed to manage to install skype on Fedora 22 with a 64 bits machine

Post like this one http://www.tecmint.com/things-to-do-after-fedora-22-workstation-installation/ and many other have suggested to install Fedy but when I do I get this error after succesfully installin fedy and choosing to install Skype from fedyd

> [MIRROR] dbus-libs-1.8.18-1.fc22.i686.rpm: Curl error (78): Remote
>   file not found for
>   ftp://mirror.uta.edu.ec/fedora/updates/22/x86_64/d/dbus-libs-1.8.18-1.fc22.i686.rpm
>   [RETR response: 550] [MIRROR] dbus-libs-1.8.18-1.fc22.i686.rpm: Status
>   code: 404 for
>   http://mirror.uta.edu.ec/fedora/updates/22/x86_64/d/dbus-libs-1.8.18-1.fc22.i686.rpm
>   [FAILED] dbus-libs-1.8.18-1.fc22.i686.rpm: No more mirrors to try -
>   All mirrors were already tried without success Error: Error
>   downloading packages:=======     ] 746 kB/s |  58 MB     00:25 ETA
>   Cannot download d/dbus-libs-1.8.18-1.fc22.i686.rpm: All mirrors were
>   tried Failed to show notification:
>   GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name
>   org.freedesktop.Notifications was not provided by any .service files

I also found this http://www.tecmint.com/skype-4-2-released-install-on-ubuntu-debian-linux-mint-and-fedora/ but since it mentions apt-get is very clear to me that it does not work for fedora even after chaning the `apt-get` to the a `dnf` or `yum` comand since no skype package is found

I have also tried downloading and installing the Fedora 16 32 bits from the skype.com downlad site but the installation has not finished after many minutes and does not provide any feedback or success result

[image: Skype for Fedora 16 32 bits does not install on Fedora 32 64 bits]

And now it has failed with a very ironic message given the combination of the name of the package and the error itself

[image: Skype failed installation]
I have also try other solutions in other forums and decided to seek help here since is a good place to get precise and updated answers

Comment: Are you taking about this http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=lpf-skype and if that is the case what if my system is a AMD A8-3520M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 4 since "The skype package is available only for i686 systems."

Comment: I'm talking about a package that could be downloaded from skype.com. Yes, they offer only 32bit builds, but it should work on 64bit.

Comment: @at8eqeq3 please read the update at the end of the post with the attached screen shot when following your advice

Comment: I believe installing via commandline will be more verbose to find where problem is. I'll try to reproduce in hour or two. Also, there's now a web version, maybe it will be enough for you.

Comment: So, I've successfully installed Skype on my Fedora 22 x64. After running `rpm -iv skype-4.3.0.37-fedora.i586.rpm` it said it requires some packages: alsa-plugins-pulseaudio, libXv, qtwebkit, qt-x11 and qt (all are 32-bit) (actually, it asks for some libraries, but it's not too hard to find which packages they belong to). When all dependencies were met, I could install and run skype (can't test if everything works but at least it starts and allows me to log in).

Comment: @at8eqeq3 you should have provided me with an answer so that I could comment on that an improve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is the steps that I made

Install skype requirements - part 1

> sudo dnf install alsa-lib.i686 fontconfig.i686 freetype.i686
>   glib2.i686 libSM.i686 libXScrnSaver.i686 libXi.i686 libXrandr.i686
>   libXrender.i686 libXv.i686 libstdc++.i686 pulseaudio-libs.i686 qt.i686
>   qt-x11.i686 zlib.i686 qtwebkit.i686

Install skype requirements - part 2

> sudo dnf install alsa-lib.i686 fontconfig.i686 freetype.i686 \
>   glib2.i686 libSM.i686 libXScrnSaver.i686 libXi.i686 \
>   libXrandr.i686 libXrender.i686 libXv.i686 libstdc++.i686 \
>   pulseaudio-libs.i686 qt.i686 qt-x11.i686 zlib.i686 qtwebkit.i686

Download skype to the `/tmp` folder

```
cd /tmp

wget --trust-server-names http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-dynamic sudo mkdir /opt/skype sudo tar xvf skype-4.3* -C /opt/skype --strip-components=1
```

Create the symbolink lynks to skype

```
sudo ln -s /opt/skype/skype.desktop /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop  
sudo ln -s /opt/skype/icons/SkypeBlue_48x48.png /usr/share/icons/skype.png  
sudo ln -s /opt/skype/icons/SkypeBlue_48x48.png /usr/share/pixmaps/skype.png
```

4.Create the skype shell file

```
sudo touch /usr/bin/skype
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/skype

cat << EOF > /usr/bin/skype 
#!/bin/sh export SKYPE_HOME="/opt/skype"

\$SKYPE_HOME/skype --resources=\$SKYPE_HOME \$*
EOF
```

5.Finally execute **skype**

Answer (score 5):

For Fedora **24** and Fedora **23** and Fedora **22** (also 64 bit!).

1. Download Skype from: http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/ and choose *Fedora 32 bit* (no 64 bit package available, but that doesn’t matter).

   In my case it was version: *skype-4.3.0.37-fedora.i586.rpm*
2. Open terminal, go to `~/Downloads/` (or wherever you have put the file) and run:

   ```
   sudo dnf install skype-4.3.0.37-fedora.i586.rpm
   ```

   and all the dependencies will be resolved automagically.

That is it!

Comment: have you tried this?

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/8738/sticky-how-do-i-install-skype-on-fedora/

Comment: it was solved as documented in my own answer

Comment: **It worked** for me with **Fedora 22**, just install it via command line with `dnf install` and all the dependencies will be resolved automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try the negativo Skype repository. It has generally always worked very well, and has support for Fedora 21+ and CentOS/RHEL 6 and 7.

http://negativo17.org/skype-and-skype-pidgin-plugin/